# Displaying multiple instances of an xml node with with xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I am styling the following xml using xslt and css. I was wondering if it is possible to set xslt to be able to select multiple instances of the  tag and style them within a single block of code. I have basically identicle  nodes with the same child nodes underneath them but they are separated by using the id="01" id="02".

here is the xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="devices.xsl" ?>
    <mpreader>
        <heading>Example</heading>
        <firmware>Firmware.134</firmware>
        <sn>123455</sn>
        <devices>
            <device id="01">
                <category>sim</category>
                <description>sim</description>
                <readable>yes</readable>
                <code size="00 18" crc="053F">test</code>
                <atr>4566</atr>
            </device>
            <device id="02>
                <category>sim</category>
                <description>sim</description>
                <readable>yes</readable>
                <code size="00 18" crc="053F">test</code>
                <atr>4566</atr>
         </devices>
      </mpreader>
```

This is my xslt. Basically what I am asking is there a way to use the block of code below to not style just  but also  without having to rewrite?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  

<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">h1{font-size:1.5em;margin-top:5px;margin-bottom:5px;}
    .deviceNum{font-size:1em; text-decoration:underline; margin-bottom:5px;font-weight:bold;}
    .deviceNum:hover .lineMov:{display:block;}
    .deviceInfo{list-style:none;font-weight:none;margin:0;margin-top:10px;padding:0;text-decoration:none;}
    .lineMov{margin-top:2px;margin-bottom:2px;}
    </style>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align:left;">
        <h1>
            <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/heading"/>
        </h1>
        <h1>
            Firmware: <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/firmware"/>
        </h1>
        <h1>
            Serial Number: <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/sn"/>
        </h1>
        <h1>
            Devices: <xsl:value-of select="count(//device)"/>
        </h1>
            <xsl:for-each select="mpreader/devices/device">
        <ul class="deviceInfo">
        <div class="deviceNum">
            Device <xsl:value-of select="mpreader/devices/device/@id"/>
        </div>
            <li class="lineMov">
            Simple Mobile
            </li>
            <li  class="lineMov">
                Category: <xsl:value-of select="//category"/>
            </li >
            <li  class="lineMov">
                Device Description: <xsl:value-of select="//description"/>
            </li >
            <li  class="lineMov">
                Readable: <xsl:value-of select="//readable"/>
            </li>
            <li  class="lineMov">
                Code: <xsl:value-of select="//code"/>
            </li >
            <li  class="lineMov">
                ATR: <xsl:value-of select="//atr"/>
            </li >
            <li class="lineMov">
                ICCID: <xsl:value-of select="//iccid"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

I would like to display each of these items under device using a list. Each new device should be displayed underneath the previous device.

Comment: Both your input document and your stylesheet are malformed. It looks like they are both missing content. Please correct. Also please show your expected output.

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. Is it possible you're not familiar with `xsl:for-each`? And/or with how to `apply` templates and use them to `match` individual nodes?

Comment: @SeanB.Durkin Alright I have edited my post sorry about the xml block I didn't copy all of it as its quite large and forgot to add the closing tags as a result.

Comment: @michael.hor257k How exactly does xsl:for-each work? would it make it possible to have my output display each device without rewriting that xsl code for each new device?

Comment: @DallanBaker "*How exactly does xsl:for-each work?*" http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_for_each.asp

Comment: @michael.hor257k I was able to get it to display the the devices in a list but it is only displaying the information from the first <device>. I have updated my code to include what I tried. How would I get it to display the information from the other <device> nodes? also my line <xsl:for-each select="mpreader/devices/device/@id"> is not correctly displaying the id of the device

Comment: Your biggest problem is that you're `<xsl:value-of` statements are using `//` at the beginning of the XPath- that means find the first such element anywhere in the entire document. That's going to give you the same one on every iteration of the `xsl:for-each`. You need a local reference, which you can easily do just by dropping the `//`.

Comment: @Flynn1179 thanks that was able to fix that problem. I am still however having an issue with my <xsl:value-of select= "/mpreader/devices/device/@id"> I tried changing it to <xsl:value-of select="device/@id> and that did not fix it. do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Inside the for-each, your context is the element you're iterating on, which in your case appears to be the `device` element. Just use `"@id"`.

Answer (score 0):

[This XSLT 2.0 stylesheet](http://xsltransform.net/bFN1y8F) ...

```
<xsl:transform
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

<xsl:output method="html" version="5" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
  <hmtl>
    <head>
      <title>New Version!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </body>
  </hmtl>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="mpreader">
  <h1><xsl:value-of select="heading"/></h1>
  <h1>Firmware: <xsl:value-of select="firmware"/></h1>
  <h1>Serial Number: <xsl:value-of select="sn"/></h1>
  <h1>Devices: <xsl:value-of select="count(devices/device)"/></h1>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="devices/device" />    
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="device">
  <div class="deviceNum">Device <xsl:value-of select="@id"/></div>
  <ul class="deviceInfo">
    <li class="lineMov">Simple Mobile</li>
    <li class="lineMov">Category: <xsl:value-of select="category"/></li>
    <li class="lineMov">Device Description: <xsl:value-of select="description"/></li>
    <li class="lineMov">Readable: <xsl:value-of select="readable"/></li>
    <li class="lineMov">Code: <xsl:value-of select="code"/></li>
    <li class="lineMov">ATR: <xsl:value-of select="atr"/></li>
  </ul>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

... will transform this input document ...

```
<mpreader>
    <heading>Example</heading>
    <firmware>Firmware.134</firmware>
    <sn>123455</sn>
    <devices>
        <device id="01">
            <category>sim</category>
            <description>sim</description>
            <readable>yes</readable>
            <code size="00 18" crc="053F">test</code>
            <atr>4566</atr>
        </device>
        <device id="02">
            <category>sim</category>
            <description>sim</description>
            <readable>yes</readable>
            <code size="00 18" crc="053F">test</code>
            <atr>4566</atr>
        </device>
    </devices>
</mpreader>
```

into this output html document ...

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<hmtl>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>New Version!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Example</h1>
      <h1>Firmware: Firmware.134</h1>
      <h1>Serial Number: 123455</h1>
      <h1>Devices: 2</h1>
      <div class="deviceNum">Device 01</div>
      <ul class="deviceInfo">
         <li class="lineMov">Simple Mobile</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Category: sim</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Device Description: sim</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Readable: yes</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Code: test</li>
         <li class="lineMov">ATR: 4566</li>
      </ul>
      <div class="deviceNum">Device 02</div>
      <ul class="deviceInfo">
         <li class="lineMov">Simple Mobile</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Category: sim</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Device Description: sim</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Readable: yes</li>
         <li class="lineMov">Code: test</li>
         <li class="lineMov">ATR: 4566</li>
      </ul>
   </body>
</hmtl>
```

### Caveats

1. I couldn't figure out what you intention was with the line item for `ICCID`, as there is no such element in the supplied sample document.
2. I excluded the `style` element in the head, because it was not part of the question, and it is a trivial exercise to take this stylesheet, and add the style elements as required.